# How do I change the photo that appears when hovering over my name?

Tags: gmail

Other people see a different photo than I do when hovering over my name. How can I change this?

I already changed the photo in the settings, and tried the contact list changes. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have to shout !! Please edit your question. Read [about] this in our [help].

Comment: Hovering over your name where? In chat or in gmail proper?

Comment: All following answers are not correct. Please follow this: Click on the setting icon on the top right -> choose setting -> General -> My picture

Answer (score 4):

This isn't about what others are doing to your account. It's an old bug where when you hover over your name in any email chain an old photo pops up on a little profile card. I just had this problem, here's how I finally fixed it:

1. Go to yourname@gmail.com and click it (top left)
2. Click account
3. Click dashboard
4. Find "Picasa" and click through to see your Picasa account. You will see the old photo in a album called "profile pictures." Just delete or add a new one!

Comment: I still face the same issue but the above answer doesn't seems working since the UI has been changed. Can you pleas update the answer accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, others can add their own photo to any of their contacts. Try it yourself: go to a contact’s details and click on **Change Picture**. You will be presented with four options: *Upload*; *Your photos*; *Profile photo*; *No photo*. If you choose anything other than *Profile photo*, you will see the photo that *you* set for the respective contact and *not* the user’s profile one.

So, if this is the case, there is nothing you can do besides asking each of your contacts to change their settings, as described above.

Otherwise, if their setting is to show your profile photo, it could be just a problem of browser cache.